# Is it possible to activate an iPhone overseas?

Tags: iphone, sim, cellular-carriers, activation-lock

My parents brought me a iPhone SE locked by Sprint from US and I only turned it on here in my country (Brazil). It was not able to reach the original network.

I wanted to unlock it but first I must activate it. Activating this device is only possible in US with a Sprint sim card or can I do it in a different way (for example, iTunes or just via internet)?

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: there are ways, but AskDifferent is not the resource for illegitimate advises.

Comment: Thank you. So there are no legit ways to do so? I have to go US and then activate it there?

Comment: Did you try with a local sim?

Comment: Locked iPhones can only be used with their respective providers in the countries of purchase. So no, you can't use it. Can you still exchange it for an unlocked model? Otherwise there are illegitimate ways to do it.

Comment: Many thanks. I called Sprint and they can only unlock my iPhone if I get a contract and wait 50 days. Apparently this is the legal way. And it sucks. Thanks Americans carriers.